# Scrapy xpath select parent element based on text value in subelement and lacking of element

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to select all elements `article` that don't contain a `span` element with class `status` and where the nested `a` element contains a `href` attribute which contains the text "rent.html".

I've managed to get the `a` element like so:

`response.xpath('//article[@class="car"]//a[contains(@href,"rent.html")]')`

But reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006929/xslt-1-0-how-to-go-for-the-parent-axis) and trying to select the first parent element `article` like so returns "data=0"

`response.xpath('//article[@class="car"]//a[contains(@href,"rent.html")]//parent::article and not //article[@class="car"]//span[@class="status"]')`

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74058871/select-xpath-element-value-based-on-value-of-another-element).

`response.xpath('//article[@class="car"][//a[contains(@href,"rent.html")]/article and not //article[@class="car"]//span[@class="status"]')')`

I don't know what the expression is for my use case.

```
<article class="car">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="/34625030/rent.html">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
<article class="car">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="/34625230/rent.html">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
<article class="car">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="/12325230/buy.html">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>  
<article class="car">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="/34632230/rent.html">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="status">Rented</span>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath expression will do the work:

```
"//article[not(.//span[@class='status'])][.//a[contains(@href,'rent.html')]]"
```

The entire command is:

```
response.xpath("//article[not(.//span[@class='status'])][.//a[contains(@href,'rent.html')]]")
```

Explanations:
Translating your requirements into XPath syntax.
"select all elements `article`" - `//article`
"that don't contain a span element with class status" - `[not(.//span[@class='status'])]`
" and where the nested a element contains a href attribute which contains the text "rent.html"" - `[.//a[contains(@href,'rent.html')]]`
I tested the XPath above on the shared sample XML and it worked properly.